# Powershell GUI how to use a selected Folder and copy its items onto a different folder in another drive

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, powershell

Using powershell and XAML, I would like the user to choose selected folder, then copy the contents from one of its sub-folders (say subfolder1) to another directory in different drive (say "C" drive). Everything works,except where I included comments.                                                DESCRIPTION of code: a User clicks on the "choose" button, and selects the desired folder. This folder path is displayed in listbox called "sourcePath". Next, user type a desired name for in "directoryName" in textbox (say "folderA"). When user presses, "create" from button, then if "folderA" exists, it will be deleted using " Remove-Item C:\$var -Recurse -Force" and created again using "Copy-Item -Path C:\"$a"\subfolder1 C:\$var -Recurse". Finally, using "Copy-Item -Path C:\"$a" C:\$var -Recurse", I want the "subfolder1" contents to be copied onto this "folderA".

```
$XAML = @'
<Window
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Folder-Browser"
Height="500"
Width="600"
>
<Grid>
 <Button Name="create" Content="create" HorizontalAlignment="Left"    
 Margin="158,175,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" />
 <TextBox Name="directoryName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23"  
 Margin="33,175,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="directoryName"  
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>   
 <Button Name="choose" Content="choose" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  
 Margin="32,47,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" />
 <ListBox Name="sourcePath" HorizontalAlignment="left" Height="45" 
 Margin="32,87,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="430"/>
 <Button Name="copyItems" Content="copy-items" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
 Margin="284,176,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121"   
 AutomationProperties.Name="copyItems" />    
</Grid>
</Window>
'@

#Parse XAML
$Win = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Parse($XAML)

# Define variables
$sourcePath = $Win.FindName("sourcePath")
$choose= $Win.FindName("choose")
$directoryName=$Win.FindName("directoryName")
$create=$Win.FindName("create")
$copyItems=$Win.FindName("copyItems")


#Event Handling
$choose.Add_Click({Select-FolderDialog})
# $a =$objForm.SelectedPath()

Add-Type -Assembly System.Windows.forms


$create.Add_Click({
$script:var = $directoryName.Text.ToString()
Remove-Item C:\$var -Recurse -Force
new-item c:\$var -itemType directory
# cannot achieve copy the contents from the "SelectedFolder\subfolder1" onto
# the new "directoryName" created. 
# Copy-Item -Path C:\"$a"\subfolder1 C:\$var -Recurse
})


# Functions
#  "Select-FolderDialog" is used for the "choose" button
function Select-FolderDialog  
{
 param([String]$Description="Select Folder", 
    [String]$RootFolder="Desktop")   

 $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
 $objForm.Rootfolder = $RootFolder
 $objForm.Description = $Description
 $Show = $objForm.ShowDialog()
 if ($Show -eq "OK")
  {
    $SourcePath.Items.Add($objForm.SelectedPath)
  }
}

$Win.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have the line:

```
Copy-Item -Path C:\"$a"\subfolder1 C:\$var -Recurse
```

In order to get a complete folder path, I would replace with:

```
Copy-Item -Path "$($sourcePath.SelectedValue)\subfolder1" C:\$var -Recurse
```

Note the extra $() around $sourcePath.SelectedValue it forces PowerShell to evaluate it as a whole.
Also, in PowerShell you can put variables inside the quotes.

Comment: Thank you, slavs. I rewrote my issue description. Hopefully, it can be interpreted ok.

Comment: Again, thank you, Slavs. It worked. One more question: how to copy all the contents from the "$sourcePath.SelectedValue". I used "Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath.SelectedValue -Destination $directoryName.Text -Recurse", but did not copy the contents from the subfolder selected. I even tried adding '\*' such as                                                            Copy-Item -Path $sourcePath.SelectedValue'\'* -Destination $directoryName.Text "

Comment: I think you are almost there. try removing the single quotes. E.g. `"$($sourcePath.SelectedValue)\*"`

Comment: Thank you, @slavs. U r Awesome. Yes, it worked. I added the Copy-Item -Path "$($sourcePath.SelectedValue)\*" C:\$var -Recurse

Comment: @BenQ happy to help. If this has answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Done, @slavs. Thank you,